# return date with specified format

Tags: javascript

I have a `date1` and I want to add interval to it and return new date as `date2`:

```js
const newInterval = 1;
const date1 = '2022-03-02T19:16:51.433Z';
const currentDue = new Date(date1);
const date2 = new Date(new Date().setDate(currentDue.getDate() + newInterval));

console.log(date2);
```

As you see my `date2` format is not same as `date1` format and I need to return the `date2` with exact format same as the date1!!

So the desired result of `date2` would be:

> '2022-03-03T19:16:51.433Z';

How can I do this?

Comment: `date1`  is a string. `date2` an actual date. Why should they behave the same way?

Comment: `date2` comes from a `new Date()`, and you only set the day of the month. Why do you expect it to have everything else the same as something otherwise unrelated?

Comment: `const date2 = new Date().setDate(currentDue.getDate() + newInterval).toIsoString()`

Comment: `console.log(date2.toISOString())`

Comment: I see no difference in the format.  Though I do see a difference in the *value* being printed, is that what you meant?  Or perhaps you're just looking for a way to format a date into a string using custom formats or culture specification?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a new date from the original date and add the interval to that:

```js
const newInterval = 1;
const date1 = '2022-03-02T19:16:51.433Z';
const currentDue = new Date(date1);
const date2 = new Date(currentDue.setDate(currentDue.getDate() + newInterval));
console.log(date2)
```